# connecting custom Create User to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have created a "new user" page using the *CreateUserWizard* on *asp.net*, I have also added another wizard step. To note, I also have an existing database (but using the built in wizard should already make one?)

When testing this I receive this error..

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

asp.net code (Create User Wizard etc)
http://codepad.org/k2Li8CTR

web config file
http://codepad.org/oNHKWoQ8

Answer (score 0):

This error can come based many variables because you are using `integrated security`.  I would use a dedicated id + pwd for your app connection unless you are configuring your ASP.NET app to impersonate the Identity that is running the ASP worker process.

But if you insist on this method then you need to understand the implications of integrated security.  For example, if the web site is challenging the browser client for creds then whatever creds are entered will be the ones used to access the DB unless you specify an impersonation.  I don't know/see if you have from what you have posted.

I would first start just making sure you have connectivity using a login ID and PWD in the connectionString and then piece by piece replace..  BUT I would discourage integrated DB access.

Comment: I know this would be bad practice but is there no possible "quick fix"?

Comment: quick fix for what?  You can easily fix using a connection string with an ID and PWD, if you are asking for quick fix for integrated then not really, you have to make sure that the credentials tied to the request are valid and exist on DB